# Obtaining Previous element in xslt 1.0 sort order, not dom order

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a CD list with entries that are not in any specific sort order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

I want to output the list in html, grouped by the first letter of the title. Since it eluded me how, I first ran the XML through a simple sort:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <catalog>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cd"><xsl:sort select="title"/></xsl:apply-templates>
        </catalog>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cd"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which then enables me to use `preceding-sibling` to check for a change in the title letter. The resulting sheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title> Booklist with books <xsl:value-of select="count(/catalog/cd)"/>
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
          table.main {width : 100%}
          table.main td {padding : 2px; border-bottom : 1px solid gray}
          th {text-align : left}
          tr.header {background-color : #9acd32}
          table.bar {border: 1px solid gray; background-color #CACACA}
          table.bar td {border-left : 1px solid gray; padding : 4px; margin : 2px; font-size : x-large}
          tr.firstbook {background-color : #CACACA}
          td.firstbook {font-size : xx-large}
          td.firstbook a.up {text-decoration: none; font-size : normal}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <table class="main">
      <tr class="header">
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> Artist </th>
        <th> Country </th>
        <th> Company </th>
        <th> Price </th>
        <th> Year </th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="cd">
        <xsl:sort select="title"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd">
    <xsl:variable name="firstLetter" select="substring(title,1,1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="oldLetter" select="substring(preceding-sibling::*[1]/title,1,1)"/>

    <xsl:if test="not($firstLetter=$oldLetter)">
      <tr class="firstbook">
        <td class="firstbook" colspan="5">
          <a name="{$firstLetter}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$firstLetter"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td class="firstbook">
          <a class="up" href="#">&#11014;</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="company"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Header link handling -->
  <xsl:template match="catalog" mode="header">
    <table class="bar">
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"
          select="cd[not(substring(title,1,1)=substring(preceding-sibling::*[1]/title,1,1))]">
          <xsl:sort select="title"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template mode="header" match="cd">
    <xsl:variable name="firstLetter" select="substring(title,1,1)"/>
    <td>
      <a href="#{$firstLetter}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$firstLetter"/>
      </a>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key part is this comparison: **`not(substring(title,1,1)=substring(preceding-sibling::*[1]/title,1,1))`** which looks at the DOM and not the result of a sort operation.

What I'm looking for is a way in xslt-1.0 to *combine* the effect of the two transformations, so I have one stylesheet, an unsorted input list and a result that looks like the two stylesheets currently produce:

[image: Screenshot from the XSLT result]

How do I do that?

Comment: For *grouping* in XSLT 1.0, see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and many, many examples here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort first into a variable (which then in XSLT is a result tree fragment), then you can use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` to convert your result tree fragment into a node-set to be processed further with your existing code.

So you need two changes, the template for `catalog` has to be

```
  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <table class="main">
      <tr class="header">
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> Artist </th>
        <th> Country </th>
        <th> Company </th>
        <th> Price </th>
        <th> Year </th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:variable name="sorted-cds">
        <xsl:for-each select="cd">
          <xsl:sort select="title"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($sorted-cds)/cd"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

and your stylesheet root has to declare the `exsl` namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
```

Note that not all XSLT processors support `exsl:node-set` while they usually support at least a similar extension function in a proprietary namespace. So assuming you want to use Microsoft's MSXML (for instance inside of Internet Explorer), then you need to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="ms:node-set($sorted-cds)/cd"/>` and

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ms">
```

Answer (score 1):

Thx to the link provided my @michael.hor I had a look at the Muenchian again. I wasn't aware that you can actually use this technique with `substring()`. Also I'm not a big fan of `for-each`.

It turned out I can use template matching and functions for keys. So the solution, running independent of extension functions, with current XSLT engines (never tested on IE, don't have that on my Linux or Mac) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:key name="cd-by-letter" match="cd" use="substring(title,1,1)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title> Booklist with books <xsl:value-of select="count(/catalog/cd)"/>
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
          table.main {width : 100%}
          table.main td {padding : 2px; border-bottom : 1px solid gray}
          th {text-align : left}
          tr.header {background-color : #9acd32}
          table.bar {border: 1px solid gray; background-color #CACACA}
          table.bar td {border-left : 1px solid gray; padding : 4px; margin : 2px; font-size : x-large}
          tr.firstbook {background-color : #CACACA}
          td.firstbook {font-size : xx-large}
          td.firstbook a.up {text-decoration: none; font-size : normal}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <table class="main">
      <tr class="header">
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> Artist </th>
        <th> Country </th>
        <th> Company </th>
        <th> Price </th>
        <th> Year </th>
      </tr>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="cd[count(. | key('cd-by-letter', substring(title,1,1))[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="title"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd">
    <xsl:variable name="firstLetter" select="substring(title,1,1)"/>

    <tr class="firstbook">
      <td class="firstbook" colspan="5">
        <a name="{$firstLetter}">
          <xsl:value-of select="$firstLetter"/>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="firstbook">
        <a class="up" href="#">&#11014;</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('cd-by-letter',$firstLetter)" mode="group">
      <xsl:sort select="title"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd" mode="group">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="company"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Header link handling -->
  <xsl:template match="catalog" mode="header">
    <table class="bar">
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"
          select="cd[count(. | key('cd-by-letter', substring(title,1,1))[1]) = 1]">
          <xsl:sort select="title"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template mode="header" match="cd">
    <xsl:variable name="firstLetter" select="substring(title,1,1)"/>
    <td>
      <a href="#{$firstLetter}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$firstLetter"/>
      </a>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thx everybody for helping!